# A way to highlight words beginning with capital letters in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, highlight

Is there a way to highlight words beginning with capital letters in notepad++?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the text you want to look at, go to `Search>Find` change to the `Mark` tab

Enter `\b([A-Z])\w+` in the `Find what` field, set `Regular expression` as the `Search Mode` and tick `Match case`, now press `Mark All`